# Parametric equation of intersection between two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have the subspace $U$, which is a plane in $\mathbb R^3
$

$$
U=\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \:2\\ \:-1\end{pmatrix}\:,\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ -2\end{pmatrix}\right\}
$$
and the subspace $V$

$V=\left\{\left(x_1,x_2,0\right)\in \mathbb R^3\right\}\:\text{where}\:x_1,\:x_2\:\in \mathbb R.$

I am to find the parametric equation for the intersection between these subspaces, which is a line.

I have tried to establish the parametric equations of the two planes:

$U=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ -1\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ -2\end{pmatrix}$
and$ \ \ \ \ V=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix},$

but I am unsure how to move forward from here.

My first intuition was to set the equations to equal each other.

$$\begin{pmatrix}s+t\\ 2s+t\\ -s-2t\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}s\\ \:t\\ \:0\end{pmatrix}$$

Does this even make sense?

Comment: do you know about the cross product of $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It doesn't make sense to equate the vectors with the same parameters $s$ and $t$ for both planes

Comment: I think @janmarqz is alluding to the solution is multiples of $((1,2,-1)\times(1,1,-2))\times(0,0,1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $s\pmatrix{1\\2\\-1}+t\pmatrix{1\\1\\-2}=\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\0}.$

That's $\pmatrix{s+t\\2s+t\\-s-2t}=\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\0}.$

From the bottom component, we see $s=-2t$.

So an answer is $\pmatrix{-t\\-3t\\0}$.

Comment: . . n i c e ...